# How to convert a column that is in a strange date format

Tags: r, date

I am working with a dataframe that basically looks like this:

`df1<-data.frame(Date=c(2019039145558,2019053191254,2019057172334))`

and I need to convert the dates to look like this:

`df2<-data.frame(Date=c(2019-02-08, 2019-02-22, 2019-02-26))`

I don't have to keep the time portion of the string of numbers, but that's great if that's possible too.

Is there a good way to do that?

I have already worked with just using gsub to replace the characters, but this dataset contains hundreds of these entries and that won't work in the long run.

Comment: Are those values in `df2` exact or is it just a dummy value

Comment: It's difficult to see how the first set of values relate to the second set, other than that the first 4 digits are the year. What's the logic for converting between them?

Comment: Is it correct to assume the following?
 - The time component is always the last 6 numbers (and is always 6 numbers long)?
 - The year component is always the first 4 numbers (and is always 4 numbers long)?
 - The month component is always 2 numbers long and immediately follows the year?
- the date could be either 1 or two numbers long and is between the month and the time?

Comment: @Russ It is better to close these type of questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `lubridate` package

```
lubridate::parse_date_time(as.character(df1$Date),orders="yjHMS")
[1] "2019-02-08 14:55:58 UTC" "2019-02-22 19:12:54 UTC"
[3] "2019-02-26 17:23:34 UTC"
```

Just the date:

```
lubridate::parse_date_time(substr(as.character(df1$Date),1,7),orders="yj")
[1] "2019-02-08 UTC" "2019-02-22 UTC" "2019-02-26 UTC"
```

For all columns:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
mutate_all(list(~lubridate::parse_date_time(as.character(.),orders="yjHMS")))

                 Date                col2
1 2019-02-08 14:55:58 2019-02-08 14:55:59
2 2019-02-22 19:12:54 2019-02-22 19:12:55
3 2019-02-26 17:23:34 2019-02-26 17:23:35
```

For some columns:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
mutate(across(Date:col2,~lubridate::parse_date_time(as.character(.),orders="yjHMS")))

                 Date                col2
1 2019-02-08 14:55:58 2019-02-08 14:55:59
2 2019-02-22 19:12:54 2019-02-22 19:12:55
3 2019-02-26 17:23:34 2019-02-26 17:23:35
```

Data:

```
df1<-data.frame(Date=c(2019039145558,2019053191254,2019057172334),
                col2=c(2019039145558,2019053191254,2019057172334)+1)
```

Comment: I think this is the only correct answer according to the OP's expected output

Comment: @akrun I think you are right!

Comment: This works! But is there a way to do it across the dataframe?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in base R with the following [date format string](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html):

```r
df1$Date  |>
    as.character()  |>
    as.POSIXct(format = "%Y%j%H%M%S", tz = "UTC")
```

*Edit: I initally misunderstood the format of the date, but have now updated the date format string based on the* `lubridate` *response in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75817457/12545041) by [@peter861222](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17918739/peter861222).*

This uses `%j`, which [means](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html):

> Day of year as decimal number (001–366): For input, 366 is only valid in a leap year.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the last six digits refer to the time and can be discarded; further assuming that day of the month is given as a number between 1-31 and can be single digit, unlike month and year:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

dates <- c(2019039145558, 2019053191254, 2019057172334)

dates |> 
  str_remove("\\d{6}$") |> 
  parse_date("%Y%m%d")
#> [1] "2019-03-09" "2019-05-03" "2019-05-07"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>